# Changing the properties of dynamic object

Tags: jquery

I've downloaded a theme (http://demo.html5xcss3.com/demo.php?cat=html5themes&host=templatesmonster&temp=point).
For my purposes I don't need the slider itself so I cut off the list items standing for the slider elements and keep just one of them.
But if I'm trying to modify any props of the slider element (in my case - background image - element with .pic class) with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pic').css('width','1000px');
  $('.pic').css('background-position','550px');
});
```

there are no result :(

If I run this function in console - everything working.
If I place an alert in this function - I can see that alert will appear after page has loaded BUT there are NO slider yet on a page.
So I presume that slider inits AFTER my function become active.

Could anyone suggest the solution?
Run function half second after page load? I don't like it actually...

Answer (score 0):

try to call this function after the slider created

```
    function test()
    {
        $('.pic').css('width','1000px');
        $('.pic').css('background-position','550px');
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get your idea. Could you make clear HOW do I run it AFTER slider creation?